# Elevation of a marker (Google Maps)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need help about "ElevationService" class and "google.maps.ElevationResult" object specification.
I have some markers and I want the elevation of them separately to include it to the text of their InfoWindows.
I couldn't understand the examples that occur in API.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There is a code example here which will help you
http://www.daftlogic.com/sandbox-google-maps-find-altitude.htm